# Using GCP connector with serverless framework

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, serverless-framework, connector

How do I deploy a Google Cloud function with Serverless framework if I need to specify a **connector**  see https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/connecting-vpc

I've tried adding these lines to serverless.yml:

```
vpc_access_connector:
  name: rojects/PROJECT_ID/locations/REGION/connectors/CONNECTOR_NAME
```

Also I tried this:

```
vpc_connector: rojects/PROJECT_ID/locations/REGION/connectors/CONNECTOR_NAME
```

As a result connector is not added.

To deploy a function I use `serverless deploy` command https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/google/guide/intro/

Comment: Post the error message you're getting. I'm not familiar with Serverless framework but I guess `rojects/PROJECT_ID/locations/REGION/connectors/CONNECTOR_NAME` would never work as a value compared to `projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/REGION/connectors/CONNECTOR_NAME`. So is that a typo on the post or a mistake that it's causing the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You have not said much about how you create and deploy the function. The link you posted mentions it is possible to edit the VPC Connector field after a function is deployed. So that should be one way. Deploy the function and then edit its settings to specify the VPC Connector to use.

**Update**

A more configurable solution might be to use a deployment manager template. You can use the one available [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/tree/master/examples/v2/cloud_functions) as a starting point. But it does not have VPC connector configuration built-in so you will need to update that template to include VPC connector configuration.

Comment: Cyac, thanks for the help. It's really possible to specify connector after deployment, but still it's not clear how to set it up with the serverless.yml file.

Comment: I am not sure about that either. If I understand correct the Serverless framework is provider (GCP, AWS, Azure etc.) agnostic. Putting something like VPC connector there would make it platform dependent. So I won't be surprised if there is no option to configure something like VPC Connector in serverless.yml. Another option is to use the deployment manager based solution I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a VPC connector by adding `vpc` property to a function in `serverless.yml`. No idea why it is not in the documentation.

```
functions:
  first:
    handler: yourHandler
    events:
      - http: path
    vpc: projects/{project_id}/locations/{region}/connectors/{connector_name}
```