# Add egress settings for VPC using Serverless framework

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, serverless-framework, vpc

I've created connector and add them to my cloud function using google cloud console but when I deployed function using Serverless framework connector has been removed from function settings.
After that I found this topic: [Using GCP connector with serverless framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58029898/using-gcp-connector-with-serverless-framework/66223531#66223531) which helps me add connector to function in `serverless.yml` using vac property:
`vpc: projects/{project_id}/locations/{region}/connectors/{connector_name}`
but I also need to add `egress-settings` to *Allow all traffic* because by default after deploying is set to *Allow internal traffic only*.
Can anyone help?